# Display structured information

Tags: sql, .net, crystal-reports

My database stores each product as its sub-products There are several tables I use to get all the information in one view. How can I arrange the data like this?

> 1. Product 1 made out of:
>
>    - Product 4
>    - Product 5 made out of:
>
>      - Product 7
>      - Product 8
>      - Product 9 made out of:
>
>        - Product 10
>    - Product 6

Every time a product´s component has sub-components, I'd like to display the details. And each time the details have sub-details, etc.

Comment: In MSSQL I have used CTE to create tree with levels then in crystal report add tabs or black space per level to create above look..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use grouping to achieve this, But before that make note of following points.

1. There should be relation ship that suggests about hierarchy.
2. Till what level hierarchy should be added like if you need 3 levels then you need to make 3 groups then acutomatically your data will be displayed in that format.

If you still need information then show how records are stored in database

Answer (score 0):

Tables:

1. Product (IDProduct,Description)
2. ProductStructure(IDProduct,IDStructure,Description) a product may have several
3. Structure(IDProduct,IDStructure,IDComponent,Description) where IDComponent is a link to IDProduct from Product table

View:

1. IDProduct, IDComponent, Description, etc...

This Is a Result from  SELECT * FROM VIEW WHERE IDProduct = 'P1':

- P1, P4, description
- P1, P5, description
- P1, P6, description

For each row(component) there is a new select that needs to be executed, in this case select from IDProduct(IDComponent) P4 and P6 would return no rows.

This Is a Result from  SELECT * FROM VIEW WHERE IDProduct = 'P5':

- P5, P7, description
- P5, P8, description
- P5, P9, description

So for each row there is a new select that needs to be executed again, untill no rows are returned wich means that the product has no components.

I cannot know how many levels a Product may have, as there are different structures for a product where depending on the path or machinery used changes it.